# WX_CONFIG_OPTIONS: command not found

Tags: linux, build-process, wxwidgets

I'm trying to [build](http://devel.aegisub.org/wiki/Build/Unix) [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.net/) on linux mint, I'm getting the following error during `./autoget.sh`

```
/home/hasenj/code/aegisub/aegisub/configure: line 25685: WX_CONFIG_OPTIONS: command not found
/home/hasenj/code/aegisub/aegisub/configure: line 25686: syntax error near unexpected token `debug'
/home/hasenj/code/aegisub/aegisub/configure: line 25686: `WX_STANDARD_OPTIONS(debug)'
```

Is there a specific package that I need to install or what exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be an Arch Linux packaging page which stated that aegisub only supported version 2.9 of wxGTK and not earlier versions however the link I used to have here in this answer is now dead and so I've removed it.

You can see from this [2009 blog post](http://blog.aegisub.org/2009/10/getting-ready-for-218.html) though that there was a non-trivial transition to wxWidgets 2.9 at this time.

Comment: Arch Linux packaging page: 404 - Page Not Found

Answer (score 0):

Someone is maintaining [aegisub deb packages for ubuntu](http://www.teufansub.uni.cc/aegiubuntu/).

Comment: aegisub deb packages for ubuntu: link doesn't make sense.